# How to calculate result from dynamic fields

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to calculate a difference between dynamic fields and then add all of the differences. I am using date fields as I need to record the difference between each group of dates and then result would be total number of years. I am providing an example as below

```
<div id="app">
<form action="">
  <div class="group" v-for="(group,id) in groups" :key="id">
    <input type="text" v-model="group.from">
    <input type="text" v-model="group.till">

    <button @click="removeGroup(id)">Remove</button>
  </div>
</form>
<button @click="addGroup">add</button>

<h2>Results</h2>
{{ result }}

<pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
```

---

So, the idea is that I should be able to calculate the difference between "from" field and "till" field in the groups array but at the same time result should reflect the sum of all differences. I tried with watch but in actual form there are a lot of fields and I might be over thinking. would appreciate some help. here is the vue code

```
var vm = new Vue({

    data: {
        groups: [
            {
                from: '',
                till: ''
            }
        ],

    },

    computed: {
        result() {
            return 0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addGroup: function () {
            var additional = {
                from: '',
                till: ''

            }
            this.groups.push(additional)
        },
        removeGroup: function (id) {
            var index = this.groups[id]

            this.groups.splice(index, 1)

        },

    }


}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a computed property. Because of `groups` reactivity any reference to `this.groups` would trigger an update:

```
import moment from 'moment'

... 

// assuming your date is a string
computed: {
    result() {
        return this.groups.reduce((group, total) => {
             return total + moment(group.from).diff(group.till, 'years')
        }, 0)
    }
},
```

**Update**

Now that I know you're working with dates, I'd suggest a library like moment or fecha. [Here's how to calculate differences with moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: Care to elaborate then? Not giving you the correct result or have I completed misinterpreted your question?

Comment: I have updated my question. See if it makes more sense now : )

Comment: Yeah, definitely more details to work with there. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks btl, but could you care to elaborate as where is the carry coming from? I am not a javascript ninja so would really appreciate an explanation if you have the time. probably just a one liner comment. thanks

Comment: thats a typo, meant to be groups also. fixed it

Comment: Thank you, i think you got the parameters wrong but I appreciate your time and at least you put me in the right direction :D